# how to keep value and value below shift (1)

Tags: database, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I want to know how to keep a value and a value below when it is equal to ("NaN"). Thank you.example

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'list': ["juan", "NaN", "Maria", "NaN", "juan", "juanita", "juan", "NaN"]})
```

I just want to continue

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'list': ["juan", "NaN", "juan", "NaN"]})
```

only when the value is "juan" and the value below is "NaN". But I do not want to use "for" ... I think something like "shift (1)"

Answer (score 1):

First, we'll get the indices of each row that contains "juan" and has a row below it that contains "NaN:

```
cond1 = df['list'] == 'juan'
cond2 = df['list'].shift(-1) == 'NaN'
idxs = cond1 & cond2
idxs = idxs[idxs == True]
```

We're almost done, but since you want to include the subsequent "NaN" rows in your final output as well, we will need to include their indices:

```
idxs = np.array([[i,i+1] for i in idxs.index.values]).flatten()
```

To get the desired output, we just select these indices from the original df:

```
output = df.loc[idxs]
```

Which gives us:

```
    list
0   juan
1   NaN
6   juan
7   NaN
```